# Twitter Bootstrap modal, HTML or Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap

I recently got involved into a Django project with Twitter-bootstrap, my experience is mainly back-end and my Javascript knowledge is not very good. I have implemented several modal in my project, but the way I handle them is pure HTML. As you can see in the docs [Bootstrap modal docs](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/javascript.html#modals), modal can be handled with HTML or Javascript. My HTML modal work pretty good, but in the need of extracting the best out of this 2-way solution I need help with two concrete answers:

1. What approach (HTML or Javascript) is more responsive to the user ?
2. What would be the advantage of taking either one(against the other) of the options(HTML vs. JS) ?

Thank you,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The HTML way is really still using JavaScript. You are just telling the JS what to do inside you HTML with different attributes. So both ways are the same for the user.

I'd say if you don't need access to any of the methods and are just using the basic functionality of the modal, then the way you are doing it makes sense.